# Site with statistics of mountaineering accidents

Tags: mountaineering, europe, canyoning

I was wondering if there was a website where I could find the different kinds of statistics of accidents in the mountains. I know that Dragon 06 (rescue service of Alpes-Maritimes) posted some numbers online in 2008. But I'm looking for more recent figures.

The data that I'm looking for includes:

- The number of accidents for each month (in the old data you really see a peak in the middle of the season).
- The state of the victim after the accident
- The cause of the accident
- The kind of accident (broken bones, cuts, ...)
- The place of the fractures
- The way the victims got evacuated
- The time between calling the helicopter and being actually rescued

I'm focusing on canyon-accidents, so if the statistics include these kind of accidents only that's a big plus :)

Comment: In German the biggest alpine club (DAV) releases accident statistic reports each year. Very informative and you could translate some key words to get the point. E.g. For 2013: http://www.google.de/url?q=http://www.alpenverein.de/chameleon/public/8a5a1748-32ef-6de4-9b4a-9461b78b9922/140805-Unfallstatistik-Uebersicht-2013_24144.pdf&sa=U&ei=jMPHVMsHyczKA_OtgYAG&ved=0CAsQFjAA&sig2=rT6sfql51EKkURpDNX8baw&usg=AFQjCNEbU1WwxR6GyOh8CmP6vXq_RUy8gQ

Comment: Worldwide I doubt it, more locally your local climbing organisation (such as the BMC in the UK) will likely have done some studies.

Comment: [For example](https://www.thebmc.co.uk/how-dangerous-are-climbing-and-hill-walking)

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that statistics on mountaineering accidents would tell you much about canyoneering accidents.

Comment: @BenCrowell, That's true. But the mountaineering accidents might tell me about the helicopter rescue. Altough I still need to look into the fact whether this is representative.

Comment: @Nick: Helicopters are seldom used in search and rescue, and I doubt that they're used at all in canyoneering rescues. Normally the people who are rolling out of bed are volunteer S&R people, who drive to the trailhead, hike in, and, if necessary, use ropes for the rescue. If you want to minimize time between an accident and being rescued, make sure that other people know where you are, when you're expected back, and how long to wait before calling 911. Stay where you are to make it easier for them to find you.

Comment: @BenCrowell I don't think it's accurate to say that helis are "seldom used" in SAR. In terms of % of people in a SAR mission sure heli crews are small, and many SAR operations are completed without aircraft by volunteers on the ground as you said. But for broad searches and extraction from remote places, helicopters are often involved.

Comment: That being said, for a canyoneering incident specifically, I agree that looking at mountaineering information is unlikely to be the most informative source. While there are some parallels, looking at whitewater rescue info is likely to yield more relevant scenarios.

Comment: @BenCrowell, according to the French alpine rescue's 2006 statistics 87% of all canyoneering rescues are done by helicopter-evacuation. So for me personally (and the course on canyon first-aid that I'm writing) it might be nice to get some extra contemporary information.

Comment: I hope you visit http://www.rockandice.com at least once in a day!

Comment: @Nick: Interesting. I stand corrected. Sounds dicey trying to maneuver a helicopter into position for that type of rescue, though...!?

Comment: @BenCrowell, usually the helicopter lands near the canyon and the rescue crew descends into the canyon installing differnt kinds of hoistsystems. Althoug it is also possible in wide canyons to land IN the canyon leading to a very spectacular yet technical rescue.

Answer (score 9):

The American Alpine club publishes this data for North America annually, though it's unlikely to cover *all* accidents.

One of the best visualizations of this data I've found is from Steph Abegg: [Mountaineering Accident Statistics](http://www.stephabegg.com/home/projects/accidentstats) and [Mount Rainier Accident Statistics](http://www.stephabegg.com/home/projects/rainierstatistics).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a source for Europe, but The American Alpine Club published "[Accidents in North American Mountaineering](http://www.americanalpineclub.org/p/anam)" annually.

> Published annually since 1948, Accidents in North American Mountaineering reports on the year’s most significant and teachable climbing incidents. In each case, the American Alpine Club analyzes what went wrong, helping you to prevent or survive similar situations in the future

As for overall statistics, I don't think there's any unified reporting system for mountaineering accidents. Each search and rescue agency and mountaineering group tends to keep their own numbers but there isn't an organization in place to collect and publish those data in aggregate.

You ask about canyon accidents and have the [canyoneering](/questions/tagged/canyoneering) tag, so I'm not sure if you're referring to mountaineering/climbing/hiking accidents that occur in canyons and ravines or if you're referring to canyoneering as in exploring rivers in canyons. If the latter, you might find more relevant scenarios and statistics by looking for data about swift water rescue. I'm not aware of any specific resources for this but they may be more readily available than canyoneering-specific data in mountaineering publications.